# How to prevent a dependency to include twice

Tags: android, gradle

[image]

My project structure is like this. But i have the same butterknife dependency in the module `app` and `qR_CodeScan`. So do i need to do something to prevent the `butterknife` to include twice in the final apk. Is it will increase my apk size?

Comment: as i know butterknife is not designed for use in android library projects. am i wrong?

Comment: @x90 Why butterknife can't be used in library project.

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dependency lib version is identical in both projects - you don't need to do something. It will be ok. You can check it through apk dex files decompilation.